# How can I pass the results returned by a method from controller to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linechart

I want to use the results returned by a method (cursor in my case) from the controller in my view,
in order to draw a graph from the data returned.
I wrote a piece of code but I have not found how to pass data to the view.

```
   //controller
    [HttpPost]
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> drawgraph(Inputmodel m)
    {
        List<Client> client = new List<Client>();
        var collection = db.GetCollection<Client>("Client");
        var builder = Builders<Client>.Filter;
        var beginDate = Convert.ToDateTime(m.date_begin).Date;
        var endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(m.date_end).Date;
        var filter = builder.Gte("date", beginDate) & builder.Lt("date", endDate.AddDays(1)) & builder.Eq("field2", m.taux);
        var cursor = await collection.DistinctAsync<double>("field2",filter);      
        return View(cursor);


    }
```

---

```
//view
 @{
   var myChart = new Chart(width:600,height: 400)
                .AddTitle("graphique")
                .AddSeries(chartType: "Line")
                .DataBindTable(dataSource: cursor, xField: "date", yField:"field2") //here I want to use the returnet result by drawgraph in the controller
                 .Write();
  }
```

Comment: You need to create a model, pass the data to it and then use the model in your view.

Answer (score 0):

You must strongly type your view to access the model :

```
 @model YourModelTypeHere @*type of the cursor variable*@
 //view
 @{
     var myChart = new Chart(width:600,height: 400)
                       .AddTitle("graphique")
                       .AddSeries(chartType: "Line")
                       .DataBindTable(dataSource: Model, xField: "date", yField:"field2") //here I want to use the returnet result by drawgraph in the controller
                       .Write();
 }
```

And then you can use Model property of the web view page to get your model.

Please see this [article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views).

Answer (score 0):

You could use

in the controller

```
ViewBag.MyData = cursor;
```

//in the view:

```
@ViewBag.MyData
```

To acceess data from controller.

But the best practice is use strongly typed views.